# How do i make two websites share same folder for storing files in ruby on rails with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Am using ruby on rails platform with carrierwave gem for uploading files.

I have two websites that share same database but different folders for storing files

```
in my uploader.rb file i have     
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

I want both websites to share same folder for storing files.

please assist

Comment: What server OS? Symlinks might work with appropriate permissions in linux servers

Comment: If you store them on Amazon S3 with carrierwave, you could have them point to the same folder, aka 'bucket'. It pretty simple to configure. Let me know if you need help!

Comment: am using ubuntu. pliz help me with configuration of both methods. The Amazon S3 and symlinks on linux ubuntu. I want to see which method will be easy

Answer (score 0):

i changed the following to

```
def store_dir
    "/path_to_the_external_directory/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def cache_dir
    '/path_to_the_external_directory/uploads'
  end
```

and everything works perfect